# WinAPI вывод значений в окошко

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть программа формирования матрицы смежности, которая считывает числа из файла.

У меня не выходит вывести матрицу в окошко.

Скажите, что нужно переделать в [коде](http://pastebin.ru/xYcoxUWl)?
Вот часть функции `About`, которая выводит матрицу:

```
TCHAR Text[300];
wsprintf(Text,("Матрица смежности", Text));
for (int i = 0; i < height;  i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height;  j++)
    {
        wsprintf(Text, _T("%s %d"), Text, matrix[j][i]);
    }
    wsprintf(Text, _T("%s\n"), Text);
}

HDC hDc = GetDC(hDlg);
RECT rc;
HFONT font;
HGDIOBJ old;
font = CreateFont(-20, 0, 0, 0, 600, 0, 0, 0, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, _T("Century Gothic"));
old = SelectObject(hDc, font);
GetClientRect(hDlg, &rc);
rc.top = 50;
SetTextColor(hDc, 0x00000000);
DrawText(hDc, Text, -1, &rc, DT_CENTER);
DeleteObject(font);
```

Comment: Думаю, читать портянки пойдут единицы. Но даже если и пойдут, формат SO такой вопрос не удовлетворит. Это не форум, тут надо задать конкретный вопрос, чтобы получить ответ.

Comment: В каком месте и в какой момент работы программы должен, по вышему, происходить "вывод"? Как имено должен происходить вывод?

Answer (score 1):

В функции `WndProc` по-русски написано что надо делать

```
    case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: добавьте любой код отрисовки...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
```

А ошибка в том, что вы строку неправильно формируете, у вас там мусор в итоге получается. Чтобы ваш инопланетный способ печати сработал, надо строку инициализировать нулями:

```
TCHAR Text[300] = {0};  // инициализируем нулями
wsprintf(Text, "Матрица смежности"); // уберем эти странные скобки и Text
```

Рекомендую для формирования строки использовать стандартный класс [std::basic_stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) как-то так:

```
#include<sstream>

...

typedef std::basic_stringstream<TCHAR> TStringStream;  // играем с TCHAR до конца

...

TStringStream text;
text << _T("Матрица смежности");
for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
     for(int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
     {
         text << _T(' ') << matrix[j][i];
     }
     text << _T('\n');
}

...

DrawText(hDc, text.str().c_str(), -1, &rc, DT_CENTER);  // рисуем строку
```

Comment: если я так пишу появляется ошибка IntelliSense: аргумент типа "const char *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPCWSTR"

Comment: @АлинаСтроителева: попробуйте `wsprintf(Text, L"Матрица смежности");`. И кстати, если уж `wsprintf`, то можно не TCHAR, а `wchar_t`.

Comment: а как изменить эти строки    wsprintf(Text, _T("%s %d"), Text, matrix[j][i]);
    wsprintf(Text, _T("%s\n"), Text);